# canActivate returns unwanted value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a `canActivate` method that I would like to implement, but for some reason(which I'm probably not aware of since I'm a newbie) the return value is happening before the `subsribe` completes.

```js
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean
    {
        debugger;
        this.ms_zehut = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'));

        this.adminService.checkIsAdmin().subscribe(res=>{
            this.isCanActivate = true;
           
        },error=>{
            debugger;
            this.isCanActivate = false;   
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/foo");
            
        });
        return this.isCanActivate;
    }
```

```js
 checkIsAdmin() : Observable<ResultOfOperation<object>>
     {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
        console.log("service before get");
        return this._httpClient.get<ResultOfOperation<Object>>(AppSettings.getIsAdmin, {headers: headers})
            .pipe(
                tap(data => { 
                    console.log("service get result", data);
                })
            );
     }
```

What should I do in order to get the result of subscription before `this.canActivate` is being returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

canActivate also accepts observable. if the return value is an observable it will subscribe to it implicitly.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean>
    {
        debugger;
        this.ms_zehut = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'));

        return this.adminService.checkIsAdmin()
    }
```

use `catchError` to handle the failed response

```
 return this._httpClient.get<ResultOfOperation<Object>>(AppSettings.getIsAdmin, {headers: headers})
            .pipe(
                tap(data => { 
                    console.log("service get result", data);
                }),
                catchError(err = > { 
                  this.router.navigateByUrl("/foo");
                })
            );
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `[ts]
Type 'Observable<ResultOfOperation<object>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'Observable<ResultOfOperation<object>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
    Type 'ResultOfOperation<object>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. [2322]`

Comment: change the return type `checkIsAdmin() : Observable<boolean>`

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is code won't wait till the API is finished.

Try async/await

more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Change the service file implementing async/await as following

```
async checkIsAdmin() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    console.log("service before get");

    const response = await this. _httpClient.get<ResultOfOperation<Object>>(AppSettings.getIsAdmin, {headers});
    return response; // check here if not json use response.json()
}
```

In the guard file

```
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.isCanActivate = await this.adminService.checkIsAdmin();


    // check the if the response returned is of 'error' or ResultOfOperation<object>
    if (this.isCanActivate === your object type){
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/foo");   
}
```

Hope this helps :)